# Can't find table2excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get table2excel "function not found" error.

Why can it not find it?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/unconditional/jquery-table2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>



   <table class="table" id="table2excel">
        <thead>
            <tr class="noExl">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Column heading</th>
                <th>Column heading</th>
                <th>Column heading</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Column heading</th>
                <th>Column heading</th>
                <th>Column heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="active">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And in callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function ReportPressCallback(param) {
                alert("Got here");
                $("#table2excel").table2excel({
                    exclude: ".noExl",
                name: "Worksheet Name",
                filename: "SomeFile" //do not include extension
            }); 

            }

</script>
```

Comment: I tried the demo for this https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel and it worked perfectly well. Where are you using the `ReportPressCallback()` function or is that part of the core library for that program?

Comment: Yes. The demo works for me too. But not when I try to port parts of it to my web app. That is a call back from when user presses a button. I assume my issue is not having link to table2query in the right place.

Comment: I edited my comment above, in asking where/how you are calling the `ReportPressCallback()` function. I don't know enough on that program to tell if it is part of the core package.

Comment: You should probably post your full code then. I may not be able to help you with it, but others might. If the problem resides in how you're using it, you should post full code. This could also be a path/permissions issue if it's an online-related issue, where `<script src="//ajax` needs to be run online and not on your local pc, if that is the case. If it is run local, then you'll need to use `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com...`

Comment: you should put the function outside your `ReportPressCallback` function

Comment: Why? That's how I call it. Where do you think I should put it?

Comment: I have the same problem, but sometimes it works inside a function, and sometimes it doesn't.